# Compare column values from multiple files

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I am having 2 files with following content. the values of column1 in both the files are always matching and in order. the values of column 2 is what i have to compare. Below are sample from both the files. I am a newbie in scripting can anyone help .

FILE1

```
tbla,2020-07-01
tblb,2020-08-12
tblc,2019-01-01
tbld,2016-02-27
```

FILE2

```
tbla,2020-07-01
tblb,2020-08-11
tblc,2019-01-02
tbld,2016-02-27
```

OUTPUT REQUIRED

```
tbla date matches in both the files 2020-07-01
tblb date mismatch found in files 2020-08-12 in file 1 and 2020-08-11 in file 2
tblc date mismatch found in files 2019-01-01 in file 1 and 2019-01-02 in file 2
tbld date matches in both the files 2016-02-27
```

i tried below but is not working

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{c[$1$2]++;next};c[$1$2] > 0' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following awk command:

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR{array[NR]=$2;next} {if (array[FNR]==$2) {print $1 " date matches in both the files " $2} else {print $1 " date mismatch found in files " array[FNR] " in file 1 and " $2 " in file 2"}}' file1 file2
```